# set 'didValidate' true only for selected fields

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, ember-cp-validations

#### Environment

- Ember Version: 2.0
- Ember CLI Version: 2.13.0
- Ember CP Validations Version: 3.4.0

#### Steps to Reproduce

**hbs:**

```
<div>
  <label> Email: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter new email" valuePath='new_email' id="new_email" didValidate=didValidate}}
  <label> Password: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter current password" valuePath='current_password' id="current_password" didValidate=didValidate}} 
  <button {{action "changeEmail"}}>Submit</button>
</div>

<div>
  <label> Confirmation Token: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter confirmation token" valuePath='confirmation_token' id="confirmation_token" didValidate=didValidate}}
  <button {{action "verify"}}>Verify</button>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

const Validations = buildValidations({
  new_email: [
    validator('presence', true),
    validator('format', { type: 'email' })
  ],
  current_password: [
    validator('presence', true)
  ],
  confirmation_token: [
    validator('presence', true),
  ]
});

export default Ember.Component.extend(Validations, {
  changeEmail: function() {
    this.validate().then(() => {
      if (this.get('validations.attrs.new_email.isValid') && this.get('validations.attrs.current_password.isValid')) {
        ...
        ....
      } else {
        this.set('didValidate', true);
      }
  });
});
```

Now when I click submit, **changeEmail** action is called and if validation fails it sets **this.set('didValidate', true);** which enables all the **three validated-input** field and shows validation error for even **confirmation_token** field. But i need to show validation error message only for **current_password** and **new_email**. vice versa when **verify** action is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way of doing is, unique property name for **didValidate**

For eg:

```
<div>
  <label> Email: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter new email" valuePath='new_email' id="new_email" didValidate=didValidateEmail}}
  <label> Password: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter current password" valuePath='current_password' id="current_password" didValidate=didValidatePassword}} 
  <button {{action "changeEmail"}}>Submit</button>
</div>

<div>
  <label> Confirmation Token: <label>
  {{validated-input model=this placeholder="Enter confirmation token" valuePath='confirmation_token' id="confirmation_token" didValidate=didValidateToken}}
  <button {{action "verify"}}>Verify</button>
</div>
```

and in js set the property to true or false manually for each field:

```
changeEmail: function() {
  this.validate().then(() => {
    if (this.get('validations.attrs.new_email.isValid') && this.get('validations.attrs.current_password.isValid')) {
      ...
      ....
    } else {
      this.setProperties({didValidateEmail: true, didValidatePassword: true});
    }
});
```

Is this the only way ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a didValidate object on the component

```
didValidate: computed(() => ({})),
```

And when you click changeEmail in the else you can do

```
['newEmail', 'currentPassword'].forEach(key => {
  this.set(`didValidate.${key}`, true);
});
```

Which creates a key for each property in the `didValidate` object and sets it to `true`.

Then in the template you can show the error for each field by passing

```
didValidate.newEmail or didValidate.currentPassword
```